# hibernate query not executing after inserting 5k row

Tags: hibernate

I am very new to hibernate so unable to detect the problem that hibernate not executing query after inserting 5k row to database via importing csv. Neither it showing error nor exception

Comment: `Neither it showing error nor exception` you have 1) misconfigured the logger or 2) swallowed the exception

Comment: Please add some more expiation to give some suggestions.